# Joining array values into string

Tags: php

I have a PHP array with multiple objects. I'm trying to join values from a certain key into one string separated by commas. Output from var_dump:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tag_id] => 111
            [tag_name] => thing 1
            [tag_link] => url_1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tag_id] => 663
            [tag_name] => thing 2
            [tag_link] => url_2
        )

)
```

The string needs to be $string = 'thing 1,thing 2'. I tried using a foreach loop, but I'm completely stuck. Could anyone help out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above answer is a little light, maybe run it as a `foreach` loop instead.

```
$names = array();
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    $names[] = $v->tag_name;
}
$string = implode(',', $names);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as this

```
$string = $array[0]->tag_name.','.$array[1]->tag_name;
```

For other elements

```
 $string = '';
 foreach($array as $object) $string.=$object->tag_name.',';
 $string = substr($string,0,-1);
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should've added in the question that the size of the array is indeed dynamic like Michael mentioned. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have edit :), try now, now he can also remove the random -1

Answer (score 0):

```
$output = '';
foreach($test as $t){
    $output .= $t->tag_name . ',';
}
$output = substr($output, 0, -1);
echo $output;
```

Comment: Jeremy Blalock's answer is cleaner :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```php
implode(',', array_map(function ($el) {
    return $el->tag_name;
}, $array));
```